# How can we use relative path for an image

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to use relative path for my logo.

But not like D:/image/logo.jpg because it might be happen that other one doesn't have D drive. So what can I do?.
and also [CDATA["../images/company_logo.jpg"]] not working in jesper

Comment: I have tried that...but not working....invalid HTTP response.
Perhaps it is not valid for jesper

Comment: Use the second answer in duplicate (pass absolute base path to report)

Comment: it has done  that with relative path...and also  mistake is I have put jesper file in resources not in reports...!!!!
Thanks.